# How do I install ffmpeg on Windows 7

Tags: apache-http-server, ffmpeg

I'm using Windows 7 and Zend server for my PHP.I have fed up completely searching and trying every methods of installation found on internet.

Luckily, I installed it well on my Ubuntu machine at my home.

*How do I install ffmpeg in Windows 7?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came across [this tutorial](http://www.vidionline.com/php/7-how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-windows), which is a good starting guide. Here you can [get the latest builds](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/).

[This page](http://ffmpeg.arrozcru.org/wiki/index.php?title=Links) lists more guides.

Also have a look at the [K-Lite Codec Pack](http://www.codecguide.com/about_kl.htm).

In general, [videohelp.com](http://www.videohelp.com/) is a good resource for setting up video stuff.

Answer (score 5):

Download either the latest [32-bit build](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/win32/static/ffmpeg-latest-win32-static.7z) or [64-bit build](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/win64/static/ffmpeg-latest-win64-static.7z) and extract the contents of the `bin` folder (`ffmpeg.exe`, `ffplay.exe`, `ffprobe.exe`) to a location on your system.  You may want to make the path short for simplicity (e.g. `C:\ffmpeg`).

Optionally, add the path to ffmpeg.exe to your system path so you can run it without the fully qualified path.

Then you can call it similarly to how you would on linux in PHP with [exec()](http://php.net/exec) or [system()](http://php.net/system).

See also the examples posted by Ahmed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a installer for ffmpeg I made hope it helps.

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Leo-Aqua/Windows-FFMPEG-installer/main/FFmpeg-insataller.bat -o %TEMP%/FFmpeg-insataller.bat -# && powershell Start-Process "%TEMP%\FFmpeg-insataller.bat" -Verb RunAs
```

just paste it in cmd

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).