# 3000 videos songs... some are loud in voice & some low.. I want to make them equal (equal in volume only)

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, internet, video-conversion

I have thousands Video flv/avi files, which are all songs only. Some of them are high in volume and some are low. Every time the song ends I have to up or down the volume at once..to escape my ears ruined by headphones... and by woofers, save my life from my neighbor sleeping after hard-earning all the day long. :-(

Any idea to make all files sound equal? 
Does such kind of application/software exist? Any converter that may convert all audio files into same volume?

I know iTunes has sound-check option but can it convert? If I want to write CDs, does any burner have the feature like this, to burn in equal sound?

I welcome any suggestions.

Comment: You may have to extract the audio tracks, use something like mp3gain to put them all to a set level, and then recombine them with the video. It's not pretty and is time-consuming.

Comment: Both Mikio and dmcgill50 answered correctly.  You will have to transcode the files to normalize the audio output.  Keep in mind transcoding data from a lossy format is destructive since compression artifacts are cumulative.  You may notice a quality decrease.

Comment: Can you mark an answer...I think we are all ready to see the winner. :)

Answer (score 1):

FFMPEG seems to be your solution for FLV file types. I would review this [article](http://blog.adtools.co.uk/easily-reduce-or-increase-flv-video-audio-levels-easily-using-ffmpeg/) which seems to be in reference to a linux environment, but will work equally as well once you have it [installed on your windows 7 machine](https://superuser.com/questions/381674/how-do-i-install-ffmpeg-on-windows-7).

For AVI file types, I would start by reviewing this [article](http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/255147-Mini-Guide-Normalizing-Audio-for-Multiple-AVI-files). As you can probably tell from the, there is some debate on how you want these volumes "normalized". There may be some highs and lows that are clipped in order to save your ears.

Your mileage may vary, as they say...

Answer (score 1):

If you want an easy-to-use GUI for it, there's the very good *mp3gain*. You can find Windows binaries for it [here](http://mp3gain.sourceforge.net/download.php).